# Authenticate with remote jenkins using CLI

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I run this:

```
curl "$JENKINS_URL/job/simple_starter/build?token=$TOKEN_NAME"
```

but I got this message:

> Authentication required  You are authenticated as: anonymous Groups
>   that you are in:    Permission you need to have (but didn't):
>   hudson.model.Hudson.Read  ... which is implied by:
>   hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead  ... which is implied by:
>   hudson.model.Hudson.Administer

I figure I can login using something like this:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar --password x --username y
```

but how do I pass my creds with the curl command so that I can trigger a Jenkins job manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All I had to do was add my Jenkins username/password to the curl command like so:

```
curl -u "${jenkins_username}:${jenkins_password}" "$JENKINS_URL/xyz"
```